# $mail -> where to put?

Tags: email, typo3

This seems to be the canonical way of [sending emails in TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html).

I have access to the back-end of a typo3 installation via my browser. I have written some HTML code that I want to incorporate into the website via the "plain HTML" widget. That HTML code lets the user input some data. I want to send that data via email. Now I read the above tutorial and I'm asking myself where they want me to put that code? I mean that `$GLOBALS` stuff and further down that `$mail` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a developer guide, thus you'll need to implement a [plugin](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html) or similar with a [controller](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/7-Controllers/1-Creating-Controllers-and-Actions.html) or handler which contains this code.

However, with TYPO3v8 you can easily create forms with the [form extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/latest/) which also allows you to send mails. This is a lot easier if you are not a developer. (The email finisher of the form extension also uses the TYPO3 mailing API of course.)

Comment: thanks for the hint but I cannot use a form. I let the user click on several dates in a HTML calendar. Then I add those dates to his selection via javascript. When he clicks on "send" I want to send those dates via email. It's not just a simple enter-your-name-and-comment thing :)

Comment: This could be achieved with a [custom form element](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/latest/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#custom-form-element-implementations) which e.g. internally simply fills a hidden field. This can be done with YAML and a Fluid template.

Comment: actually, can you explain what you mean by plugin with controller or handler? and: is plugin = extension?

Comment: I've just added links to the Extbase/Fluid book for plugin/controller setup. The book is quite outdated but it should get you started.